# XML Validation error as I start Mule embedded into WAR file

Tags: eclipse, mule

I have web app with embedded in it Mule 2.2.1) I am using eclipse Kepler.
I have no validation error in eclipse as I open mule config file. however as I attempt to start my web app in eclipse using WTP, I get xml validation error

This is snippet that causes me problem...

```
<service name="someServiceName">
<inbound>
      <vm:inbound-endpoint path="xyz.cache"/>
           <quartz:inbound-endpoint jobName="getXXX" cronExpression="">
       <transformers>
           <bean-builder-transformer beanClass="com.xyz.MyBean">
                            <bean-property property-name="messageId" expression="message.id" evaluator="mule"/>
           </bean-builder-transformer>
       </transformers>
    <quartz:event-generator-job />
 </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
</inbound>.....
 </service>
```

The short version of error is :

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'property-name' is not allowed to appear in element 'bean-property'.
```

If I change `property-name` to `name`. I am able to start my WAR file, but eclipse starts giving validation errors as I open my mule config file.

I think this is parser issue, but working with MAVEN I am not sure which specific jar should I exclude or include. If you are in the mood to help, I can provide complete error..

Thank you for your help.
Boris

Comment: What happens if you package the WAR and run it in your favourite container? I'm trying to see if the issue is a side effect of running with WTP or a dependency issue in your POM.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute name [is](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.x/modules/spring-config/src/main/resources/META-INF/mule.xsd#L4810) property-name indeed. However it haven't been like that always, in the [past](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-2.2.1/modules/spring-config/src/main/resources/META-INF/mule.xsd#L2379) it was just called name.

The change was necessary because if multiple bean-builder-transformers use beans with same property name there would be spring registry conflicts as the name property has spring connotations.

The change [happened](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/commit/ca4bc968c9666fb70ef4a1e3786e4d6f31844979) in 2.2.7. Given that you are in 2.2.1 my guess is that you have multiple bean-property (in different bean-builder-transformers) using the same name.

I would suggest you to upgrade to 2.2.7 or later.

Comment: hey Victor, thank you so much, man for your kindness and sharing expert knowledge.

Comment: Victor, thank you so much for sharing knowledge. I am not sure I would be allowed to upgrade to 2.2.7. I am not sure I understand your explanation. You are saying, that the change was made because of "multiple bean-builder-transformers use beans with same property name", but I have in my mule config only one bean-builder-transformer, only one that I provided in my prior message. if I have only one  bean-builder-transformer in my mule config file. how is it possible to have multiple bean-property (in different bean-builder-transformers) using the same name ? Thank you again for your help.